# Start Pikaday calendar closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, pikaday

The Pikaday calendar comes opened when the page loads, there's some option for it to start closed and open just after the trigger is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

By default when you generate `Pikaday` element it's not showed by default and it's only triggered when user generate `focus` event on the vinculated `input` field.

If you provide some sample code we can help you better, however based on what you ask I suppose that you're using the example from `pikaday.jquery-plugin`which is on [github pikaday repository](http://dbushell.github.io/Pikaday/examples/jquery.html). This example shows the calendar when the page is load because it's executing the follow `js`:

```
var $datepicker = $('#datepicker').pikaday({
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
    maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
    yearRange: [2000,2020]
});
// chain a few methods for the first datepicker, jQuery style!
$datepicker.pikaday('show').pikaday('nextMonth');
```

If you take a look at this code you can see that the `pikaday` it's not showed by default, the function which shows the calendar it's explicitly called, if you remove the follow line the calendar is not showed when the page load, only when you focus on the `input`:

```
$datepicker.pikaday('show').pikaday('nextMonth');
```

Hope this helps,